# find the next record that contains [some stuff]

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working on a report that contains inpatient ("IP") surgical visits and the service dates of the follow-up x-ray visits, which is based on patient type and revenue code:

```
MRN    AdmitDate     Pattype    RevCode    ServiceDate
123    1/1/2015      IP         100        *null*
123    *null*        PT         200        2/1/2015
123    *null*        SVO        320        2/10/2015
123    *null*        PT         200        2/15/2015
```

I'm trying to roll up rows 1 and 3 on a single line to appear as follows:

```
MRN    AdmitDate    Pattype    FollowUp
123    1/1/2015     IP         2/10/2015
```

but am getting either an empty return or just the next record in the dataset using @followup =

```
If {encounter.pattype} = "IP" then
    if next ({encounter.pattype}) in [several different patient types]
        if {charge_detail.revenuecode} in ["0320" to "0324"] then
            {charge_detail.servicedate}
```

Comment: Why are you using next function

Comment: But for rows 1 and 3 Pattype is not the same?? 3 has SVO...??? Also if you really want to do that, easiest I can think of is to group by Pattype..

Comment: Correct, the patient type changes depending on their date of service, so inpatient stay (row 1), then SVO (single visit outpatient, aka x-ray) on row 3.  That eliminates the grouping aspect since I need things on one line.